# Action hook for OpenShift Node.js app does not execute, despite setting execute permission

Tags: node.js, git, shell, openshift

I created a new Node.js app on OpenShift. I added a post_deploy shell script action hook and ran `git update-index --chmod=+x post_deploy.sh` to add execute permissions to the script. Then I committed and pushed the change to my OpenShift repository.

During deployment, the action hook is not run. I ssh'ed into my OpenShift application and I was able to run the script from the command line. I ran `ls -l` in the action_hooks directory and noted that post_deploy.sh's permissions are `-rwx------`. If my understanding is correct, that means that the script has executable permissions only for owner. Does the execute permission need to be set for all? Could this be why my action hook does not execute on deploy?

How do I get my action hook to execute during deployment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that your filename is wrong. It should be `post_deploy` and not `post_deploy.sh`. Try renaming it and seeing if it works.

---

From the [action hooks documentation](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-action-hooks.html), the the default build lifecycle actions are:

1. pre_build
2. build
3. deploy
4. post_deploy

You can the deployed versions (by default) at `~/app-root/repo/.openshift/action_hooks` when [ssh'd into your gear](https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202535020-How-do-I-access-my-application-s-gear-directly-), and try running them from there. If it indeed a permissions issue, it will become apparent here.

You can interactively edit the files in this directory and run `gear deploy` on your gear to help the troubleshooting process—it should call the `deploy` and `post_deploy` hooks when you run this command.

Comment: Your solution is correct. Removing the file extension solved the problem. Thank you.